# How to get color by id from another android xml file

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm new in android development and I facing with the following problem:
I have .xml vector images in drawable and I want to create several color presets for them.

As I understand it, to achieve this purpose i need to create sets of colors for presets in colors.xml and then get a certain set i need.

The question is how can I get, for example,
`<color name="input_lines">#ffffff</color>` 
by "input_lines" name from image.xml file?

I tried to use `*"@android:color/input_lines", "@colors/input_lines" and "@android:R.color.input_lines"*` but it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's not `"@colors/input_lines"`

if you are talking about referring to a color that is from `colors.xml` into another `.xml` file , then it's `"@color/input_lines"`.

but if you are referring to that color from activity  then it's

```
int color1 = getResources().getColor(R.color.input_lines);
```